# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in Ubuntu with flask

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I am trying to save a file to my static folder with flask running on ubuntu 20.4 to the following directory: /var/www/webApp/webApp/static/temp/3.png'
When I try to save it gives me the following error log:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 1696:tid 139769597695744] [client xxxxxxxxxxx] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/webApp/webApp/static/temp/3.png', referer: http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/upload
```

I have set the folder premission to 777, and in the webapp.conf folder I have the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 34.65.173.45
    ServerAdmin email@mywebsite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/webApp/webapp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/webApp/webApp/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/webApp/webApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/webApp/webApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I save my file with the following code:

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static', 'temp', filename))
```

This is working on local host.

Can someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you go to the project folder /var/www/webApp/webApp/ and run

```
sudo chmod 777 -Rv static
```

Comment: I will get back to you in a couple hours

Comment: chmod 777 is never a good idea and even dangerous. This is like removing the door and windows in a highly criminal neighborhood. Permission denied problems always can be resolved by comparing who needs access and what permissions are set on a folder/file

Comment: @J.G. How do I do that? I am a complete noob with ubuntu

Comment: This works I don't care about security because I worked on this for so long

Comment: You can you use permission rule 755 for preferred security, 777 allows everyone to modify or delete the file.